# wowza android mobile stream doesn't work

Tags: stream, rtsp, live-streaming, wowza

I configure the wowza Stream server for vod and live streaming. Then I try to stream rtsp url in vlc In my machine, it’s work fine. But I try same vod rtsp url in my android mobile phone it doesn’t work. I try different machine vlc player to stream same url it also doesn’t work. Why it happen. How can I configure wowza server in android rtsp mobile streaming.

Comment: Check if the ports are forwarded / not blocked

Comment: pls.. can you tell me how to check blocked ports

Comment: http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/. See if the server answers on 554, 1935.

Comment: I check the port but those port are not use in another process.

Comment: Problem is in the firewall, firewall doesn't allow Wowza to stream. I disable the firewall and then try, it"s work fine.